# How do I add a new country to the default locales list in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, locale, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I added a country field to one of my content types with the "Country" module, which works like a charm. Now I would like to add countries like "Rest of the World" or "England" or "Scotland". Any idea how one can alter the default country list of Drupal 8?

Comment: Country module is currently in develpment , so i thik you need to check if an API is provided in source code like 'hook_country_list_alter' or something like it and alter by yourself

Comment: Yes, that hook is available and working, thank you Fky!